# Fork JUNIT execution

Tags: java, junit, ant, fork

I have been struggling with this for quite some time today. Wonder if anyone could help

**Aim**
To try and reduce the time taken on JUnit execution. I am trying to fork out 5 VMs, each providing a container for a subset of tests to execute. I believe I have enough memory (5 VM * 3G each=15GB) on my machine to handle the load.

I am trying to use the forkmode="perBatch" mode. However, with the ANT file below, I am unable to see the 5 VMs being forked. The JUnit tests aren't executing in parallel as well.

Where am I going wrong?

```
   <target name="runTestSuite" depends="JunitTestsCompile">
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" failureProperty="runTestSuite.failure" showoutput="false" fork="true" forkmode="perBatch">
      <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=3072M"/>
      <jvmarg value="-Xms3072M"/>
      <jvmarg value="-XX:+UseParallelGC"/>
      <jvmarg value="-server"/>
      <jvmarg value="-Xmx3072M"/>
      <jvmarg value="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"/>
      <jvmarg value="-Djavax.xml.parsers.XmlDocumentParserFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl" />
      <formatter type="xml" />

      <classpath location="${instrumented.dir}" />
      <classpath location="${classes.dir}" />
<classpath>
  <path refid="junit.classpath"/>       
  <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
  <pathelement location="${src.main.dir}/project/properties"/>
  <pathelement location="${src.main.dir}/build/svr/cls"/>
  <pathelement location="${src.main.dir}"/>
  <pathelement location="${src.aspects.dir}"/>
  <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/junit.jar"/>
</classpath>

<!-- Execute all tests -->
<batchtest todir="${junit.log.dir}">
     <fileset dir="${build.dir}" > 
        <include name="my/org/whatever/something/abc/myTest.class"/>
   </fileset>
 </batchtest>
<batchtest todir="${junit.log.dir}">
     <fileset dir="${build.dir}" > 
        <include name="my/org/whatever/something/abc/myTest2.class"/>
   </fileset>
 </batchtest>

<batchtest todir="${junit.log.dir}">
     <fileset dir="${build.dir}" > 
        <include name="my/org/whatever/something/abc/myTest3.class"/>
   </fileset>
 </batchtest>

<batchtest todir="${junit.log.dir}">
     <fileset dir="${build.dir}" > 
        <include name="my/org/whatever/something/abc/myTest4.class"/>
   </fileset>
 </batchtest>

<batchtest todir="${junit.log.dir}">
     <fileset dir="${build.dir}" > 
        <include name="my/org/whatever/something/abc/myTest5.class"/>
   </fileset>
 </batchtest>
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending some more time on this, I discovered that the JVM fork would just fork out a new JVM, not necessarily in parallel. If we want parallel Junits, we are better off using the ANT parallel construct.